# How would I change the background color of an HTML file if the screen size is too small using a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I change the background color of an HTML file if the screen size is too small using a javascript function? For example I need the background of my HTML file to be gray but if the window size is less than 600px it turns red. I did it with CSS but need to do it in java script. Here is what I have in CSS

```
<style> 
body {     
  background-color: gray; 
}  
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {     
  body {        
    background-color: red;     
  } 
} 
</style>
```

Comment: 600px height or width?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in javascript? I believe the way you did it in CSS is the generally accepted best way to do something like this.

Comment: doesn't make sense to do it with javascript when media query works

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of:
[Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3437786). You should be able to find your answer there. But if not, this website goes more in depth on how to get height and width with live updates of each method (not every method gives the same value). http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: @forgivenson I need it for a class where the teacher likes us to use as much javascript as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check window size using resize event 
 `<body onresize="changeColor()">`

Add following function to implement your logic

```
<script>
//Check if window width is less than or equal to 600,then change bg
function changeColor() {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    if(w<=600)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I also ran the function onLoad to get the background color right away

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      if($(window).width() < 600){
        $('body').css('background-color','red');
    }else{
     $('body').css('background-color','grey');
      }
    });
```

Comment: might wanna add `$(window).resize(function() {})`.

Comment: oh yes! we can add it.

Answer (score 1):

Plain javascript:-

```
if (window.screen.availWidth < 600) {
      document.body.style.background="#FF0000"
}
```

for jQuery, use `$( window ).width();` method.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to attach to the global `window` object's `onresize` event. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize).

Then, you can check the window size and act accordingly. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth).

eg,

```
window.onresize = function(){
 if (window.innerWidth < 600){
  // set colors
 } else {
  // set other colors
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you could do

```
function resize(){
   if($(window).width() < '600'){
         $('body').css('background','#000');
     }
     else{
          $('body').css('background','#fff');
     }
};
$(document).ready(resize);
$(window).resize(resize);
```

Comment: be more effective in a resize handler and trigger the resize on page load

Comment: obvious to who though ... possibly not to OP

Answer (score 0):

It's doesn't really makes sense to do such a thing in JavaScript now that media queries are supported in all major browsers, but if you wan't to target older browser as well, this will do the trick:

```
var backgroundColorCheck = function() {
  if ( window.screen.availWidth <= 600 ) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
  else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}; 
// bind our backgroundColorCheck function to the resize event:
window.onresize = backgroundColorCheck;
// call backgroundColorCheck function to make an initial check of the width:
backgroundColorCheck();
```

Comment: when I have this in dreamweaver it works as it should but in the web browser it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do the trick. It will fire once the page loads, and whenever the user changes the window size.

```
document.onload = checkWidth();

window.onresize = checkWidth();

function checkWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    }
}
```