# Change div background based on screen size. Using JS and change CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I looked at this specific post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29515979/14802095
though I don't know how to reference a specific class.

I know that I definitly want to include

```
document.onload = checkWidth();

window.onresize = checkWidth();
```

except I don't know how to change the background of a div depending on the screen size of the device/the size of the current browser windows.
Here's kind of how I have it right now
*I'm using Bootstrap for CSS*

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6 background1 border-design">
  <p>Placeholder</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

for CSS

```
.background1 {
 background: linear-gradient(100deg, #87CEFA 0%, #FF8C00 100%);
}
.background2 {
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, #FF8C00 0%, #C0C0C0 100%);
}
```

And say that I want it so when the browser window size is ≥576px (since I'm using col-sm-6) to have it use .background1 but when the browser window size is less than or equal to 576px, to use a different css style, say .background2

Answer (score 0):

The property `classList` gives you the list of classes attributed to a DOM element. You can then add the expected properties according to the screen size.

A possible implementation would be:

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="to-modify" class="col-sm-6 background1 border-design">
  <p>Placeholder</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then, for the JavaScript, we can do:

```
window.onresize.apply(updateBackground);

function updateBackground(){
    let window_width = window.innerWidth;
    if (window_width >= 576) document.getElementById("to-modify").classList.remove("background1").add("background2");
    else document.getElementById("to-modify").classList.remove("background2").add("background1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You don't have to call the function `checkWidth`, JS will automatically call it, you just have to pass the reference

**2)** You can use `add` or `remove` method of `classList` to add or remove a class on the html element.

```
container.classList.remove("background1");
container.classList.add("background2");
```

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".bg-container");

function checkWidth() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    container.classList.remove("background1");
    container.classList.add("background2");
  } else {
    container.classList.add("background1");
    container.classList.remove("background2");
  }
}


document.onload = checkWidth;
window.onresize = checkWidth;
```

```css
.background1 {
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, #87CEFA 0%, #FF8C00 100%);
}

.background2 {
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, #FF8C00 0%, #C0C0C0 100%);
}

.bg-container {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="bg-container col-sm-6 background1 border-design">
    <p>Placeholder</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this, but with multiple background, besides numbering each function ( like checkWidth1(), checkWidth2() etc...) for each  div background

Comment: I'm confused, I tried that with my code, didn't work, and then create a new html, css, and js file and pasted your code into it, and the browser still gave the same error? MS Edge Version 91.0.864.53

Comment: @jasonhe Please see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58s06mLx/1/). It is working as expected. For simplicity, I've added the color `red` and `blue`.

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. Had to do with how I was loading the js file locally.

Answer (score 0):

### You can do it only using css

```css
    .background1{
    background-color: red;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px)
    {
     .background1
     {
       background-color: green;
       color:white;
     }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div id="to-modify" class="col-sm-6 background1 border-design">
  <p>Placeholder</p>
 </div>
</div>
```